# Programatically set the image fit to div tag when image size or dive size change without streching the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

First of all I got the image size before load the img tag.

```
 function getImageDimensions(path, callback) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            callback({
                width: img.width
                , height: img.height
            });
        }
        img.src = path;
    }
```

**usage**

```
var image_he = img.height;
var image_wi = img.width;
    getImageDimensions(response.data.url, function (data) {
      var img = data;
      image_he = img.height;
      image_wi = img.width;
    }
```

Then I use this function to resize the images in order to div size.(actually this `img` tag is in the `iframe`. To better understanding I used `div` tag instead `iframe`)

**I called bellow function before set the image.**

```
function doResizeImgTag(){
    var ifs = window.top.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");//get all iframes
    console.info(ifs);
    for (var len = 0; len < ifs.length; len++) {
        if (ifs[len].src == unescape(window.location.href)) { //get relevent iframe by checking current iframe name
            var cliIframeHeight = ifs[len].clientHeight;//get iframe height
            var cliIframeWidth = ifs[len].clientWidth; //get iframe width
            var ratio_ = 0;
            if (img.width > cliIframeWidth && img.height < cliIframeHeight) { 
                angular.element('#photo-id-eu').css('width', "100%");
            }
            else {
                if (cliIframeHeight > cliIframeWidth) {
                    ratio_ = (cliHeight / img.height) * 100; //ratio calculation
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        angular.element('#photo-id-eu').css('height', ratio_ + "%");
                    });
                }
                else {
                    ratio_ = (cliIframeHeight / img.height) * 100;
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        angular.element('#photo-id-eu').css('width', ratio_ + "%");
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

**Non fit image.(I want to fit this like 2nd image)**

[image]

**Best Fit image.**

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a "working" example? Also, if it doesn't need to be in an img-tag, you could set the image as a background-image and set background-size to cover.

Comment: So you want an image to fill the size of it's parent element right? If that's right you can do this with CSS - div img {width:100%;} ... you can set a max  width too if you need div img {width:100%; max-width:300px;}

Comment: some time when we set width:100% it hide the some part from the bottom if image size width is more larger than image height.

Comment: `object-fit` plus JS polyfill for older browsers; or display it as a background image with background-size.

Comment: This is bit hard to give the working url. Because I am getting image from my CCTV camera getting through the DVR. some time there's high resolution camera and some time just 3:4 resolution camera used. so I need to display that image in html page.But main div's are should be the same size always.